# Can't scroll Background

Tags: android, background, scroll, andengine, live-wallpaper

Can anyone tell me how to make background of live wallpaper scroll? Default launcher in phone doesn't scroll since Android 4.1 update. However, certain third party launchers do scroll the background. Regarding my live wallpaper; I have added `onOffsetchanged`, yet the background doesn't scroll. Can anyone help me?

**Here is the code**

```
final AutoParallaxBackground background = new AutoParallaxBackground(0, 0, 0, 5);
background.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0f, new Sprite(0, 0, backgroundRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager())));
    mScene.setBackground(background);
```

Answer (score 0):

check by adding with the following line

```
auto_background.setParallaxChangePerSecond(5.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new ParallaxEntity(5f or -5f, new Sprite(0, 0, backgroundRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()));
```

The first parameter of ParallaxEntity must be greater than 0 to move right ,negatvie values to move left

Comment: thanks for your answer.but problem is when i add an item for ex clouds over the background the clouds doesn't move